# Magento for each loop limit

Tags: magento-1.9, category, php

Working on the categories for a magento homepage for pulling out categories on the main page.

At the moment it pulls all out of the categories out but I want to limit this too 6 categories.

I have tried a few different options and have not been able to get this working correctly.

What would be the best way to apply the limit? I have included code below.

```
<ul class="cat-nav">
<?php
    $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
    $storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
    Mage::registry('current_category') ? $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : $currentCategoryId='';
    foreach ($storeCategories as $_category):
?>
        <li class="<?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>">

            <?php $categoryChildren = $_category->getChildren(); ?>
            <?php if($categoryChildren->count()) : ?>
                <ul>

                    <?php foreach($categoryChildren as $_categoryChild) : ?>
                        <?php $_categoryChildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryChild->getId());?>
                        <?php $categoryGrandchildren=$_categoryChild->getChildren(); ?>
                        <li class="<?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>">
                            <?php
                                $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                echo '&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryChildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryChild->getName() . '' . $_categoryChildModel->getProductCollection() . '</a>';
                            ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php if($categoryGrandchildren->count()) : ?>
                            <?php foreach($categoryGrandchildren as $_categoryGrandchild) : ?>
                                <?php $_categoryGrandchildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryGrandchild->getId());?>
                                <li>
                                    <?php
                                        $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                        echo '&emsp;&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryGrandchild->getName() . '(' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getProductCount() . ')</a>';
                                    ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome on Magento SE. Use a category collection, it'll give you more control over the limit rather than resorting to use a counter and if's :)

Comment: Hi Im not too sure as to how to do this? I thought this would be the better way and just limiting them within the foreach loop

Comment: easier yet dirtier. [here](http://www.magentoworks.net/manipulate-collections-of-products-in-magento/) is a link for the manipulation of products to give you a rough idea of what you should do.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a list of categories based on the parent id like this:

```
$parentId = 'Your parent id here';
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parentId)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addAttributeToSort('position')
    ->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(6);//limit to 6 categories
```

To get the root categories use `$parentId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId()`.
For the sub categories use `$parentId = 'the category id for which you are trying to retrieve the child categories.'`